# How to pass ApplicationDbContext to ASP.NET MVC5 constructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5

Well in my ASP.NET MVC application all controllers use this ApplicationDbContext object. At this moment it is being instantiated inside controller constructor, but this is tight coupling and is not a good practice.

```
    public MessagesController()
    {
        this.Db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        this.Mapper = new MessageMapper(Db);
        this.Service = new MessageService();
    }
```

Ideally I want this ApplicationDbContext to be passed as a parameter to each controller's constructor, like this scenario with dependency injection:

```
public MessagesController(ApplicationDbContext context){
    this.Db = context;
    this.Mapper = new MessageMapper(Db);
    this.Service = new MessageService();
}
```

The question is, how to achieve this? I tried to find the source code that controls controller dependency injection, but it comes as .NET dll file and I cannot modify(just like you cannot edit System namespace files). So how is dependency injection possible for controllers in ASP.NET MVC? Can anyone use my scenario as an example? Thanks.

Comment: There are many IoC frameworks with MVC adapters. See http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection for Unity

Comment: Actually you want to pass the Service as a dependency too. If the Mapper is actually a Repository, then it should be injected instead of the ApplicationDbContext which is a _persistence detail_. Btw, properly using DI means you inject into constructor only the services (repository is a service too) you need, not all the dependencies required to do things yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Also I was wondering, if I want to inject something like Controller.Server into a class called ImageUploadService, how can I do this? The issue is that Controller.Server is not available inside the controller's constructor, but only made available in controller actions. I want to make sure the Controller.Server passed as dependency is always this same instance.

Answer (score 1):

Install this package:

```
Install-Package Unity.Mvc5
```

In your Application_Start() add this line:

```
protected void Application_Start()
  {
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();                           // <----- Add this line
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
  }
```

In UnityConfig register your type:

```
container.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Done.

**Update**
btw, by doing this you will just move the code that creates new object to Unity. Buy you are still waiting for concrete class. In addition you will have all the data manipulation operations in your controller (read: UI). If you really want to get rid of tight coupling you might want to take a look at DAO pattern. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object

Comment: Thanks for your advice. So Unity is like a dependency injection container? What is the magic behond container.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>()? Does it create an ApplicationDbContext object when a class asks for this dependency?

Comment: Also there is a problem. The ASP.NET MVC5 controllers come with dispose method, which disposes the ApplicationDbContext object upon controller garbage collection. If the controllers aint even aware of ApplicationDbContext, how can I refactor this Controller.Dispose()\ method? Can I move the logic to Repository and call Repository.Dispose() instead?

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you my approach to this.

Off the bat, you don't want the DBContext exposed directly to the controller. Infact, to truly leave a seperation of concerns you dont want the controller to even know about a `DbContext` at all.

If you where told that the company plan to start using a different storage technology, for example, **RavenDB** or **MongoDB**, each and every one fo your controllers would need refactoring. The `DbContext` is no required or useful.

I dont know what the `MessageMapper` class is, but it does take a `DbContext`, and that too would break.

You need to look at adopting the **Repository Pattern**.

Read this article, it should help.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Yeah it is exactly what I am going for right now. I am refactoring the application, and will pass Repository and Mapper to controller constructor, without ApplicationDbContext at all in future. The Mapper takes DbContext in constructor for historical reason, which is bad because the Mapper is only supposed to map between Model and ViewModels, not to access data from database. This is why I am refactoring with Repository pattern. Thanks for your tips.